# Getting the affected rows when altering a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, report, constraints, unique-constraint, rows-affected

I need to retrieve a report of the affected rows when a table has been altered with the following commands:

1.- Changing the engine:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> ENGINE=INNODB;
```

2.- Adding constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla ADD PRIMARY KEY símbolo_clave_foránea;
ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla DROP PRIMARY KEY símbolo_clave_foránea;

ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla ADD FOREIGN KEY símbolo_clave_foránea;
ALTER TABLE nombre_tabla DROP FOREIGN KEY símbolo_clave_foránea;
```

3.- Adding a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Do you mean which rows would fail in terms of the constraints?

Comment: Yes @TonyHopkinson the affected rows that show some kind of warning and the ones that would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary or Unique Key failure is look for duplicates, if you have nulls in there you'll need to sort them first.

E.g given `MyTable(KeyField int not null)` then

```
Select KeyField From MyTable
inner join (Select KeyField,Count() as NumberOfTimes Group By KeyField) Duplicates
Where NumberOfTimes > 1
```

Then you'll have to come up with something to do with them. Delete or rekey.

Foreign Keys just a outer join query with where key is null

e.g Given `MyTable (KeyField int not null, ForeignKeyField int not null)` and
`MyLookUpTable(LookUpkey int not null, Description VarChar(32) not null)` then

```
Select KeyField From MyTable 
Left Join MyLookUpTable On MyTable.LookUpField = MyLookUpTable.LookUpKey
Where MyTable.LookUpField Is Null
```

Again you'll have to decide what to do with them. You could delete them, but this might help.
One way is to insert a "Missing" Record in the look Up Table, grab it's key, then do an update with join. So given that key is 999

```
Update m
Set LookUpField = 999
From MyTable m 
Left Join MyLookUpTable On m.LookUpField = MyLookUpTable.LookUpKey
Where m.LookUpField Is Null
```

Now you can dig out 999s and deal with them at your leisure.

Comment: Well you'll need to do that to have a foreign key, but other than that, nothing to do with what you asked for.